# How to add external jars in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, dependency-management, bndtools

I'm unable to successfully add and use these external jars from my Eclipse Repository.

> > org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.annotation-4.0.3
> >     org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.runtime-4.0.2
> >     org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.shell-4.0.3
> >     org.apache.felix.dependencymanager-4.2.0

I get no errors at the **Add Files to Repository** window:

[image: Success Here]

I, however, get an error warning pop-up window after clicking on the **Finish** button.

[image: Error]

```
'Building Workspace' has encountered a problem
Errors occured during the build.
```

I then get the error below whenever I add them from the Available Bundles tab into the Run Requirements tab and then try to resolve the Run Requirements *(even though I have added all the jar)*.

```
org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve <<INITIAL>> version=null: missing requirement org.apache.felix.dependencymanager
```

How can I successfully add and use these jar files to my project?

**Eclipse**

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Build id: 20150924-1200

**Java:**

java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)

Comment: Right click your project, and click Properties. From the left hand side options, select Java Build path. Then click on libraries tab. Click add external jars to add external jars to your project.

Comment: @Ankit That way they don't appear in the **Run Bundle Descriptor**. They don't list under the **Available Bundles** tab.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Ankit. Would you please mind looking at this other related question I have [**HERE**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214434/jar-file-dependencies-missing-at-runtime)? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Eclipse Equinox](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/) is the OSGi framework developed in the frame of the Eclipse foundation. Deploying on the Eclipse platform means deploying OSGi bundles in Equinox.

You are using [Apache Felix](http://felix.apache.org/), which is the OSGi framework developed in the frame of the Apache foundation.

According to your explanations, it seems you are trying to install Felix as an Eclipse bundle:

> [...]add and use these external jars from my Eclipse Repository.

If you wish to develop an Eclipse project which would be deployed as an OSGi bundle in the Apache Felix framework (and not an Eclipse plug-in project), the Felix Documentation details [how to integrate Apache Felix with the Eclipse IDE](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/development/integrating-felix-with-eclipse.html). It seems in this documents snapshot are out of order, but the general procedure should be right. Three ways to include the Felix runtime are specified, an Eclipse repository does not seem to be the right way.

Comment: Thanks for your response @bdulac. Would you please mind looking at this other related question I have [**HERE**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214434/jar-file-dependencies-missing-at-runtime)? Thank you in advance.